# How to get a time between two columns of type time? 

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, time

I have a table in SQL Server

```
id int, 
enters time, 
left time, 
date datetime,
user varchar(50)
```

Now I want to get the time difference between `enters` and `lefts` but I get this error message:

> Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Operand data type time is invalid for subtract operator.

How can I to get the time has passed?
For example, if user enters at 8.00 and leaves at 9.15 I need to get 1.15.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
declare @MyTable table(enters time, lefttime time)
insert @MyTable values('8:00', '9:05')

select *,
    cast(datediff(hour, enters, lefttime) as varchar) + ':' + 
        right('0' + cast(datediff(minute, enters, lefttime) % 60 as varchar), 2)
from @MyTable
```

**[EDIT]**

Added `0` padding to avoid showing `1:5`, instead of `1:05`.

---

Another way to do this:

```
select cast(dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, enters, lefttime), 0) as time)
from @MyTable
```

The result will be of `time` type, not `varchar`.

Comment: Please be careful using CAST/CONVERT/DECLARE etc. with VARCHAR and no length. In some cases this will become a VARCHAR(1), in other cases a VARCHAR(30). When it becomes a VARCHAR(1) you will be dealing with invalid data. Always declare varchar(x) and not just varchar (well, all the char types, actually).

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand - You are saying `In some cases this will become a VARCHAR(1)`. Can you show how it can become VARCHAR(1) in this particular case?

Comment: Not in this particular case, but I am talking about the practice in general. Better to form a habit of always declaring the length, especially if you are giving sample code for others to learn from.

Comment: DECLARE @foo VARCHAR = 'xxx';
 SELECT @foo;

Answer (score 4):

Look at [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function.

```
DECLARE @enters datetime = CAST('2011-06-26T08:00:00' as datetime);
DECLARE @left datetime = CAST('2011-06-26T09:15:00' as datetime);

SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(HH, @enters, @left) as varchar(max)) 
    + ':' + CAST(DATEDIFF(MI, @enters, @left) % 60 as varchar(max))
```

Comment: Why do you do datetime cast in the declaration?

Comment: Also OP says that columns are of type `time`, not `datetime`.

Comment: @Alex: OMG! Give OP chance to read manual. About 1st question: better readability + compatibility with other DBMS

Answer (score 1):

```
select
     id
    ,enters
    ,[left]
    ,date
    ,[user]
    ,CONVERT(time,DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second,enters,[left]), 0)) as [Difference]
from
    MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

> Simple method is
>
> convert the DATE to time datatype
>
> convert()
>
> and then use substring to find the
>   difference based on the position
>
> between substr(date,0,0) and time